# Swift 4 - Multiple tableview cell types in a random order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a to do list app and in the list tableview, there needs to be 3 types of tableview cell. One for a task, one for an event and one for a reminder. Each cell has different elements inside it (multiple labels, different images etc...)

I would like to be able to use 3 different cell types in the same tableview.

I have created 3 UITableViewCell classes, each with the cell constraints and setup inside. And within my core data model, there are 3 entities. One for a task, event and reminder.

Also, it's a to do list app so the cells should be arranged in any order and any number of each custom cell.

So using:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {...} etc...etc...
```

would not be viable.

Any help or ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the 3 different cells to be randomly ordered?

Comment: It's unclear, but I don't think it's about random, it's about "how do I know which cell to use because the order of the item (either task, event, reminder) is not guaranteed to be the same. Is that it? If that's the case, I hop you use 3 different objects/struct in an array to populate your UITableView, and you have a way to know if it's a reminder/task/event, right? Let's call that difference "type". Then, just check the "type" and dequeue the corresponding the cell.

Comment: Choose the cell type based on the data in your data model at the given index path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the dequeue the cell according to the kind of item you have, not according to the indexPath.

Either you have three Struct/Classes for your Event/Reminder/Task:

```
struct Event { ... }
struct Reminder { ... }
struct Task { ... }
```

And:

```
var myTableViewArray: [Any] //Array of either Event, Reminder, Task objects.
```

In `tableView(_:cellForRowATt:)`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let object = myTableViewArray[indexPath.row]
    if let event = object as? Event {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCellId" for:indexPath) as EventCell
        //configure cell with event
        return cell
    } else if let task = object as? Task {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCellId" for:indexPath) as TaskCell
        //configure cell with task
        return cell
    } else if let reminder = object as? Reminder {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReminderCellId" for:indexPath) as ReminderCell
        //configure cell with reminder
        return cell
    } else {
        //We shouldn't get into this case, but return an UITableViewCell here?
    }

}
```

If you have the same object, or because you added a protocol simulating that, but with a property giving if it's an Event/Reminder/Task, like an enum:

```
enum Type {
    case event
    case reminder
    case task
}

struct CustomObject {
   let type: Type
}
```

Then, instead of:

```
if let event = object as? Event {}
else if let task = object as? Task {}
else if let reminder = object as? Reminder {}
```

Just do a simple switch:

```
switch object.type {
   case .event:
       //Dequeue the EventCell
   case .task:
       //Dequeue the TaskCell
   case .reminder:
       //Dequeue the ReminderCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to your data model(s) that will keep track of its sorting order in the current todo list. Sort that data model with respect to that attribute and it'll be ready for the table indexPath.

It could be an Integer. When switching todo locations, you modify this attribute.

This opens up a potential overhead because you have to update other todos as well and their sorting order. (eg: todo #5 moved to location #2, have to modify the attribute of the bottom part todos of the list).

If you aren't expected to manage tens of thousands of todos that could be sufficient. Oherwise, you'd need more sophisticated mechanism such as floats or strings and normalize them once in a while in the background.